# How set QLabel in a corner of Windows even when i do resize in QT?

Tags: c++, qt

I am currently working with OpenGL and i need to place a QLabel in a corner of my window, and when I make a resizing in the window, the label goes back to the corner of the window.

I am using the function

```
void MyClass::myFunction()
{
    label->move( mapToGlobal( QPoint( 460, 425 )));
}
```

And in my paintGL() method

```
void MyClass::paintGL
{
   myFunction();
}
```

but when i maximize the window, i can not put the label back in the corner. I have read other topics but i can not find the solution.

[image: Example gif]

Comment: You could put the QLabel in a QGridLayout together with expanding spacer items. Then the layout takes care of positioning the label correctly.

Comment: even when maximizing or minimizing the window? the only drawback is that for this label i'm not using a .ui file, I'm creating everything by code

Comment: Yes, if the widgets are set up correctly. You may want to look at http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html

Comment: Ok, i found the solution. 

replacing move method for setGeometry.

    label->setGeometry((this->width() - label->sizeHint().width() / 2),
                       this->height() - label->sizeHint().height()/ 2,
                       label->sizeHint().width(), label->sizeHint().height());
thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i found the solution.

replacing move method for setGeometry.

```
label->setGeometry((this->width() - label->sizeHint().width() / 2),
                   this->height() - label->sizeHint().height()/ 2,
                   label->sizeHint().width(), label->sizeHint().height());
```

thanks a lot.